# MySQL date separated as day/month/year

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table, called `schedules`. It has three columns `day`, `month`, `year`, the the day/month/year that schedule is for. There is no timestamp here. I chose this format so that I could for instance retrieve all the schedules for October, or for the year 2014.

However, is it possible to retrieve the schedules for given range, say from Sept 10, 2014 to Oct 09, 2014? The problem is that if I use

```
WHERE 'day' > 10 AND 'day' < 9 ...
```

will not return anything since even though the month October (10) is larger than September (9), the days of the month will miss this up!

Is there a way or do I need to also include a fourth `date` column with a timestamp?

Comment: why in separate columns?, you can extract day/month/year on a timestamp/datetime field and you can compare date ranges easily.

Comment: This should all be in a date field and then use proper date functions rather than trying to mash some horrible mess together. Rework your database design instead and the queries for this are trivial.

Comment: Yes. Sound logic, but an unfortunate conclusion. The date and datetime data types exist for a reason!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parenthesis and an `or` clause:

```
WHERE ('month' = '9' AND 'day' > 10) OR ('month' = '10' AND 'day' < 9)
```

However, using a datetime field would be much better, as you can still get month/day/year easily:

```
WHERE MONTH(field) = 10
WHERE DAY(field) = 3
WHERE YEAR(field) = 2014
```

and then you also can do

```
 WHERE field >= '2014-09-10' AND field <= '2014-10-09'
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html for documentation on all the date/time functions in mysql.